# Will aluminium foil wallpaper to reduce WiFi interference damage walls due to humidity?

Tags: home

The problem with WiFi reception isn't so much signal strength, rather that all the channels are in use by people in the neighborhood. The WiFi analyzer picks up a vast number of signals from houses up to 250 meters away, so the best way to improve the signal is to block all these other WiFi signals. That's why I'm considering using aluminium foil wallpaper, my own WiFi signal comes from below, so this will move through the ceiling and the floor of the room I'm in.

What I'm concerned about is that aluminium foil will block water vapor, so humidity may build up on the wall causing fungus.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik If you have an answer, please post it in the 'answer' section below, not in comments. Thanks.

Comment: @RobertCartaino, stop deleting comments before the information is repeated in an answer. (Or better still, stop deleting comments at all.) And please, do not delete this answer before MANY people have seen it.

Comment: Then please do not post answers in comments. Comments do not have the features necessary to vet whatever is said here, and folks coming across this site aren't going to understand the nuanced difference between an off-the-cuff answer posted immediately below the post and one posted properly in the answer section. Comments are not for answers; answers are for answers.

Comment: As a side effect, you will lose cellphone reception. Just switch to 5GHz or wired connection like normal people...

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if aluminium foil will block humidity or not. But what I know is that you don't have to use solid foil to obtain Faraday Cage effect.

Actually, there are some materials in the form of the net that would work as good as aluminium foil. And probably those materials would't block water. [Here](https://www.emfanalysis.com/fabrics/) are some short list of this kind of materials but probably you could find a lot of cheaper examples. I think even steel or copper net with small holes would be enough.

Answer (score 3):

A lot of the insulation products we use over here in Belgium have a kind of aluminium foil that should always be installed to the inside of the building.
This is a vapour block that is meant to keep the (air) moisture inside the building and thus to avoid getting water in the insulation (and the walls).
So putting aluminium foil on the inside of your walls should not cause you any trouble with moisture.

Answer (score 1):

How to avoid interference with Wifi. Change the channel to unoccupied one. Change orientation (polarization) of antenna. If all the other router antennas are vertical go horizontal.  This will reduce by itself your interference to them as well as their interference to you. Google antenna cross polarization for more info . Going horizontal can also make your signal directional. One channel in the 2.4 GHz will have major interference at meal times because it used the same frequency as a microwave oven (2.450 Ghz). Google WIFi channel frequencies for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Another good option is to change channel;if you could find which is less used your signal strength will be improved. But in any case technically other wifi signals is not block or effect your signal strength as much as you can feel.

Using proper antenna for your needs is important.Many people thinking that more dbi increase the strength yes but also no.The main subject here to be inside coverage area. Please check this picture to understand the coverage with which dbi.
[image: Coverage Area by DBI]

Also avoid Most three mistakes many people do :

**1-Signal blockage :** *Be sure nothing blocks signal no obstacles between.*

**2-Incorrect antenna type or placement :** *The receiver antennas should be angled apart in a wide “V” configuration, which provides better pickup when the transmitter is moving around and being held at different angles.*

**3-Poorly coordinated frequency set :** *A properly coordinated set of wireless frequencies must satisfy two criteria:a)Frequencies must avoid local active TV channels
b)Frequencies must be mutually compatible*

The reason why should be carefull about the setup of your antenna is here shown in these schema and pictures :

[image: Modem antenna setup mistake]
[image: Here is the antenna coverage]

Comment: Point 3: Wifi signals are well above broadcast television frequencies therefore no interference . Both  transmitter have to be on the same channel in order to work. Point 2: Vertical is great if you want to broadcast everywhere. However this person wishes only up from the basement to an upper level -straight up and down

Comment: @resident_heretic changing angle of the antenna will help to arrange coveraga area that is why I put last pic. Making V angle will also help you to cover up or downstairs however it is really important to reduce obstacles which means less wall.While you can  not drop walls you have to set modem's position best for less obstacles around.